# Panel text alignment in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am trying to create this mobile app where when I shrink the window size to its minimum size, but all hell breaks loose.

The text wraps, due to which the alignment of the panel breaks. I tried various styles but couldn't make it work. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bootply snippet - Boxed Layout (SO)</title>
<meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="" />
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/bootstrap/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/bootstrap/img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/bootstrap/img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">




</head>



<body >

<h2 class="text-center">Club</h2> 
<div class="container"> 
<div class="foo col-xs-6 col-md-3"> 
<div class="panel panel-default"> 
<div class="panel-heading text-center" >Candy Crush</div> 
<div class="panel-body"> 
<img class="img-responsive center-block" width="310" height="310" alt="Cinque Terre" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pack1-baco-flurry-icons-style/512/Game_Center.png"/> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="foo col-xs-6 col-md-3"> 
<div class="panel panel-default"> 
<div class="panel-heading text-center">Whack</div> 
<div class="panel-body"> <img class="img-responsive center-block" width="310" height="310" alt="Cinque Terre" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pack1-baco-flurry-icons-style/512/Game_Center.png"/> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="foo col-xs-6 col-md-3"> 
<div class="panel panel-default"> 
<div class="panel-heading text-center">Title</div> 
<div class="panel-body"> <img class="img-responsive center-block" width="310" height="310" alt="Cinque Terre" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pack1-baco-flurry-icons-style/512/Game_Center.png"/> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="foo col-xs-6 col-md-3"> 
<div class="panel panel-default"> 
<div class="panel-heading text-center">Quake</div> 
<div class="panel-body"> <img class="img-responsive center-block" width="310" height="310" alt="Cinque Terre" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pack1-baco-flurry-icons-style/512/Game_Center.png"/> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript' src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this style on
panel title :

```
style="overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"
```